# How to identify unasscoiated NUnit tests from Azure Test Plans test cases?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, nunit, test-explorer, test-plan

Is there a way to identify which NUnit tests are not associated with a test case from within Test Explorer in Visual Studio?

I want to identify new tests that have been added by the team and ensure they have a test case reference in Azure Test Plans

**Update:**
Is there some kind of filter or non-obvious method for filtering tests that are not associated with test cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio, to check whether a test method has associated to a Test Case in Azure Test Plans, you can do like as below:

1. Open you test project in Visual Studio.
2. On **Test Explorer**, right lick on the test method you want to view, then select "**`Associate to Test Case`**" option.

   [image]
3. On the pop-up window, under "**`Existing Associations`**" section, you can see all the Test Cases which have been associated with current test method.

   [image]

---

Comment: Thanks Bright Ran, but I am now realising my question wasn't specific enough. I understand the above, it was more of, is there some kind of filter I can use within Visual Studio to find the unassociated, automated tests, rather than go through them one by one, especially as we are in the hundreds now.

Comment: @MarkyMark, I have attempted the following filters in the search bar of Test Explorer: **`-Traits:"Azure"`**, **`-Traits:"Test Plans"`**, **`-Traits:"Test Case"`**. But none of them can work as expected. I did not find other methods in Test Explorer can filter the tests that are not associated to Test Cases. In the Test Explorer, there is also no column to show the associated Test Cases. So, I am afraid that there is no method to quickly filter the tests that are not associated to Test Cases in Test Explorer.

Comment: Thanks Bright Ran. 

I figured there would be something obvious if Microsoft had implemented something.

It looks like I am going to have to rely on the developers to tell me if they add anything!  What could possibly go wrong!

Comment: @MarkyMark, Yes. Currently, to check whether the tests have been associated to Test Cases in Test Explorer, you need to open each just like as the steps mentioned in my above answer. In addition, you also can try to report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio) to ask the engineer team to add a column to show the associated Test Cases in Test Explorer of Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks and will definitely add a request in the Developer Community.

Comment: @MarkyMark, You're welcome. And if the suggestions on this answer are helpful for your case, maybe, you can accept it. This could be also helpful for other people who have the similar questions.